# Why does this perfectly fine SQL query not work in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following query that works perfectly fine on MySQL Workbench. I included backticks so that node.js should be able to handle it:
createdb.sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `clients`;

USE `clients`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_data` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_id` VARCHAR(255),
  `uses` TINYINT,
  `auth_time` DATE,
  `last_cash` MEDIUMINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

The code is simple enough, yet returns a syntax error:

```
const mysql = require ('mysql')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const fs = require ('fs')
dotenv.config()
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : process.env.MYSQL_KEY,
    port: 3306
  });
   
  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
   
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
  });

let createQuery = fs.readFileSync ('./queries/createdb.sql').toString()
createQuery = createQuery.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ");
console.log (createQuery)

connection.query(createQuery, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw (error)
    if (results) console.log (results)
    if (fields) console.log (fields)
})
```

I have no idea why this perfectly fine query doesn't work... any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: When you call fs.readFileSync('./queries/createdb.sql').toString(), this will read in the file as a string. However, it looks like you're then replacing line breaks with spaces using the replace method. This may be causing issues with the syntax of your SQL query when it's executed by the MySQL

Comment: Instead of replacing line breaks with spaces, try using the trim method to remove any whitespace characters from the beginning and end of the string:

`let createQuery = fs.readFileSync('./queries/createdb.sql').toString().trim();`

Comment: And delete this line `createQuery = createQuery.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ");`

Comment: Also, most (if not all) SQL connector libraries do absolutely fine with newlines in the query string, no real need to remove them. @OP include the error you received. A nitpick as well, use `;` more consistently: it won't affect the code, but it's just kind of messy to "sometimes" include it.

Comment: @robertklep: Absolutely that was the problem, it works like a charm now.

Comment: @Tushar I tried trimming or not doing anything at all and both worked. The original trim was only in there in case the new lines were causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql` driver, by default, doesn't support multiple statement queries due to security concerns (explained [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries)).

You can enable multiple statement support like this:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : process.env.MYSQL_KEY,
    port     : 3306,
    multipleStatements: true
});
```